# checking values of array using strcmp and nested loop

Tags: c, arrays, loops, strcmp

I have reached the final part of the program and I am facing some issues once again.

---

Issue #1: When I print the separated string parts of the array in the while loop of the tokenizing, the values are ok. BUT, when I print the `puts(tokenArray[1])`,it results in only one letter of the command been shown, e.g: Input: "qwe rty" | Printout in `while` loop: qwe rty | Printout using `puts(tokenArray[1])` outside the loop: "e" (yes, just the letter).

---

Issue #2: I noticed this while debugging. After I enter a random input and then enter "history", the `tokenArray` has first position filled with "history", and the next position filled with "tory". For that, I cannot use the nested loop and the strcmp as you can see below, in order to check if the first part is "history" and if so, check the second part. If the second part is empty, to just show the history of commands, or if it "1"/"2" etc (when the user has entered "history 1", to execute the first command in history.

This is my progress so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int i=0; int j=0; int k=0;
    char inputString[100];
    char *result=NULL;
    //char *result2=NULL;
    char delims[] = " ";
    char historyArray[100][100] = {0};
    char historyKey[] = "history";
    char *tokenArray[100] = {0} ;
    //char exitString[] = "exit";

    do
    {
        printf("hshell>");
        gets(inputString);
        strcpy (historyArray[k], inputString);
        k++;

        // Break the string into parts
        result = strtok(inputString, delims);


        while (result!=NULL)
        {
            //result2 = result;
            tokenArray[j] = result;
            //puts(result);
            result= strtok(NULL, delims);
            //puts(tokenArray[j]);
            j++;
        }
        //j = 0;
        puts(tokenArray[1]);
        if (strcmp(tokenArray[0],historyKey) == 0)
        {
            if (strcmp(tokenArray[1], " " ) == 0)
            {
                for (i=0; i<k; i++)
                {
                    printf("%d. %s \n",i+1,historyArray[i]);
                }
            }
        }
        else if (strcmp ("exit",inputString) != 0)
        {
            printf("\nCommand not found \n");
        }

    } while (strcmp ("exit", inputString) != 0);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: sidebar: *Never* use `gets()`. It is so bad its been deprecated as of C99 and not even present in C11. It is terrible. Use [`fgets()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) with `stdin` instead.

Comment: I had `fgets` but then my program didnt do anything, no exiting, no array copying. thats why I used `gets()`, everything I types was resulting in "Command not found". Any ideas on that?

Comment: That would be odd indeed. I assume you used `stdin` and provided the appropriate length for your input buffer. There is another issue within the code if that is the case. I'm looking it over right now. that was the first thing that caught my eye.

Comment: Yes, it looked like this `fgets(inputString, 100, stdin);`. Ok, thank you

Comment: The problem when using `fgets()` is that it *keeps* the linefeed at the end of the line, which `gets()` doesn't. Typically you don't want it, so you either have to ignore it when comparing, or look for it first and remove it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several things immediately apparent.

1. You're never resetting the value of `j` from one command line to the next.
2. `strtok()` is not going to tack an single-space string into your input tokens just because you enter something like "command ". It will strip the delims, so your logic is flawed with this idea. The input tokens for "command " will be a single token, for "command one " it will be "command", and "one" only. You're apparently thinking it will give you a single-space string from what you're doing with `strcmp(tokenArray[1], " " )`.
3. Major, but not related your immediate problem, eventually you will overrun your stack when `k` becomes large enough (100 commands to be precise)
4. Kudos to @unwind, you need to throw out the newline fetched with `fgets()`, which I did when testing this. Prolly shoulda mentioned that.

Fix the first one, rethink the second, and consider an alternate structure for holding history for the third.  Finally, I tested this with `fgets(inputString, 100, stdin);` and it does work, so no idea what is wrong on your end there.

Comment: I guess I had #1. commented out for some reason I dont recall. The way I thought of this part of the problem is this: break the input ("history 1") into parts. Insert the first part in `tokenArray[j]` and the second in `tokenArray[j+1]`. Then check: if the first is "history", check if first is empty..etc Isnt that correct?

Comment: @voth1234 were I to do this i would keep the token splits as the history in a structure and parse it token at a time, side by side against the input line.

Comment: that seems like a more logical approach. I will try that. Thank you. EDIT: How do you throw out the newline?

Comment: @voth just find the last char in the string and set it to zero  (0) if it is a '\n' char. Be careful, btw, in handling a string with 0-length going in, which technically you shouldn't have.